# How to see the unit test result in the framework AceUnit?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm getting started with AceUnit in Ubuntu but I don't know how to see the result of the Unit test

The first thing that I made, was trying with the example test called "basic". I generated the AceUnit.jar file with the command

```
 make -s -j
```

Then I pasted in the directory of the example, the next step was to generate the "AceUnitTest.h" file with the command

```
 java -jar AceUnit.jar AceUnitTest >AceUnitTest.h
```

After that I run the makefile and compiled correctly but I don't see any file or some kind of graphic way to probe that the test was successful. Maybe there is something that I have been doing wrong an I hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: Don't have experience with AceUnit. But you should check AceUnit documentation, it may help. http://aceunit.sourceforge.net/manual